Can I download call log and text messages from an Android device's if I'm connected to its WiFi hotspot?
Someone has a Samsung Galaxy A14 as well as I do. Now, I'm connected to its WiFi hotspot.
I want to know if I can download their call log and text messages.

Hotspot only provides Internet connection. No access to phone internals like messages is possible.

Hotspot is an internet connection only. You can't spy on wifi or wired connections. Otherwise,  everyone would be looking inside your phone as well.
Also, most items are encrypted on the phone. It requires the initial pin to decrypt them.  If you had that, then you would not need to try this via hotspot.
